# Uploading a blob using HttpWebRequest in silverlight 5 causes SecurityException

Tags: c#, web-applications, httpwebrequest, silverlight-5.0

I want to create a **silverlight5 application** to upload a file in blob storage using http request but when I end the response using

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);
```

it throws a 'Security error'. I have searched a lot for it and what I found is to upload a clientaccesspolicy.xml file to the root of my storage account. I have uploaded this file to my storage account at root level but it is not working. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. Content in clientaccesspolicy.xml was bit wrong. I was using * in uri for domain

```
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
      // for me, this line was was giving an error (using * for uri) 
      //   <domain uri="*" />
      //  now I am using 
         <domain uri="http://*" />
         <domain uri="https://*" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

thanks :)